# Simple PHP script to arrange file links in text file (array)

Tags: php, arrays, move

Im trying to code a simple web/text based file editor that has categories for links to a files on webserver and these categories also have archives for older files once uploaded.

Simple to do but for example inside "Animals" category in the file management I want to reorder cats dogs pigs birds, move single item up and down... how can I move items up and down inside an array?

If someone already has an idea for ready made solution, I paste my idea here:

One catergory on a web page looks like this:

Animals:
 - Cats (link: /files/cats.jpg)
 - Dogs (link: /files/dogs.jpg)
 - Pigs (link: /files/pigs.jpg)
 - Birds (link: /files/birds.jpg)
      Archive:
      - Older Cats (link: /files/oldercats.jpg)
      - Older Dogs (link: /files/olderdogs.jpg)
      - Older Pigs (link: /files/olderpigs.jpg)
      - Older Birds (link: /files/olderbirds.jpg)

Category is saved on a single text file on a server (Animals.db) . Archive file is a separate text file (Animals-archive.db). User is able to create and delete categories.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend jQuery's UI Sortable:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 0):

```
function move($array, $from, $to)
{
    if ($from === $to) return $array;
    $array2 = array_splice($array, $from);
    $element = array_shift($array2);
    $array = array_merge($array, $array2);
    $array2 = array_splice($array, $to);
    $array[] = $element;
    return array_merge($array, $array2);
}
```